# How to schedule a script to run every day for Python

Tags: python

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

Date = today

headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US, en;q=0.5'}
URL = ['https://www.amazon.com/Dove-Intensive-Concentrate-Technology-Protects/dp/B0B1VVXTKL',
             'https://www.amazon.com/Dove-Intensive-Concentrate-Conditioner-Technology/dp/B0B1VXFLQ2']
data = []
for url in URL:
    webpage = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content)
    data.append({
        'Rank': soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[2].get_text().split()[0],
        'Category': " ".join(soup.select_one('#detailBulletsWrapper_feature_div span:-soup-contains("Best Seller")').contents[2].get_text().split()[2:6]),
        'Date': Date
    })
    
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
# to local file
#pd.DataFrame(df).to_csv('myfile.csv', index=False)

#Export to onedrive
local_path = '/Users/ja/OneDrive - insidemedia.net/amzbestranktest.csv'
df.to_csv(local_path, index = False)
```

Hi guys, I am trying to schedule this script to run every day at 8am. Right now this is what I have: I am trying to use schedule and print. But I am not sure how to use that with the script that I have.

```
def amzbestrank():
    print()
    
Schedule.every().day.at("12:45").do(amzbestrank())

While True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

#local drive Append 
#df.to_csv('myfile.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False)

#Onedrive Append 
#df.to_csv(local_path, mode='a', header=False, index=False))
```

Answer (score 6):

1. Open a text editor, such as Notepad.
2. Type the following code:
3. Save the file as "DailyScript.py."
4. In the Windows Task Scheduler, create a new task.
5. In the "General" tab, enter the name of the task and select how often you want it to run.
6. In the "Triggers" tab, select "New."
7. In the "Begin the task" drop-down, select "On a schedule."
8. In the "Settings" section, select "Daily" and enter the time you want the task to run.
9. In the "Actions" tab, select "New."
10. In the "Action" drop-down, select "Start a program."
11. In the "Program/script" field, enter the full path to the Python interpreter, such as "C:\Python27\python.exe."
12. In the "Add arguments (optional)" field, enter the full path to the "DailyScript.py" file.
13. Click "OK" to save the task.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your answer won't work in this case, because the questioner most likely works on `macOS`, while your Answer is pointed towards `Windows`. Besides that, it seems like your answer is missing code.

Comment: @Mime The answer doesn't need code (it's just providing steps for how to use the Task Scheduler's GUI)

Comment: @SuperStormer Probably, but they refer in their second point to "Type the following code" without any code following

Comment: @Mime If you think his answer lacks context why don't you try submitting and ```Edit``` so that you make it better ? I totally agree with @SuperStormer that a correct answer to this question doesn't need code as it follows a different, step-by-step, approach and focuses on how to solve any problem of that kind. In my opinion, that should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 5):

`pip install schedule`

```
import schedule
call_me=lambda:None
schedule.every().day.do(call_me)
```

Comment: [A code-only answer is not high quality](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/392712/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers).  While this code may be useful, you can improve it by saying why it works, how it works, when it should be used, and what its limitations are.  Please [edit] your answer to include explanation and link to relevant documentation.

Answer (score 2):

As it seems like you are working on `macOS`, you should use a [`cronjob`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Cron).

Simply open up a terminal and type `crontab -e`.
Append the file with the following line.

```
0 8 * * * python /path/to/script.py
```

This will execute the command `python /path/to/script.py` everyday at 08:00.
Note that `/path/to/script.py` refers to your first code snippet, as the second code snippet is no longer needed

Comment: Thank you so much for answering. Yeah, I am on Mac. What if I want to stop the code, is there anyway to stop the code to run daily?

Comment: SImply open `crontab -e` again and delete or comment (with `#`) `0 8 * * * python /path/to/script.py`

Comment: If you don't want the script to run daily, you can also specify the days of a month or the weekdays the script should be run at. For more information see [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Cron#Crontab_format)

Comment: Cron doesn't work for me sadly, Do you know how to define in a schedule library so it will keep running?

Comment: Can you please explain what doesn't work? What is the output of `crontab -l`?

Comment: (base) jasonyao@Jasons-MacBook-Pro ~ % crontab -l
* * * * * Python3 /Users/jasonyao/Downloads/testrank.py       This is what I am seeing I did it on a min by min to test it out but nothing happens after every min. I also tried just python instead of python3 and doesn't work either:(

Comment: Your `crontab -l` shows two possible error sources. First of, it should be `python3` instead of `Python3` (note the lower p), as `Python3` will most likely not work. Second, you may should be use the full path to the `python`-executable. Find the full path with `which python` and edit the `cron` job (e.g. `/usr/bin/python`).

Answer (score 1):

The best practice is to use `crontab` which comes with OS by default. In windows, it is known as `Task Scheduler`. In Other OS such as Linux and macOS, it is done by the beautiful tool CronTab.

Following is a simple CronTab example that runs a python script every Tuesday at 5:00 AM.

```bash
0 5 * * TUE python3 /User/Mustard/Desktop/hello.py
```

If you are unfamiliar with cronjobs scheduling, you can prepare one here with https://crontab.guru/